# visual studio typescript "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at...."

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, typescript, import

I am learning typeScript with visual studio and trying to do a simple class export. I have seen this problem many times, but none of the solutions helped me. what am I doing wrong ?

- I have changed module system from CommonJs to system
- I have installed npm systemJs
- tried instead of "import" to write "/// ...reference path.... /  "

still the same error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at..."

```js
import { Address } from "./address";

class Customer {
  protected name: string = "";
  public addressObj: Address = new Address();
  private _CustomerName: string = "";
  public set CustomerName(value: string) {
    if (value.length == 0) {
      throw "Customer name is requaierd"
    }
    this._CustomerName = value;
  }
  public get CustomerName(): string {
    return this._CustomerName;
  }
}
```

```css
export class Address {
        public street1: string = "";
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="address.js"></script>
  <script src="Customer.js"></script>
  <script>
    try {
      cust = new Customer();
      cust.CustomerName = "doron";
      cust.addressObj.street1 = "test"
    } catch (ex) {
      alert(ex);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

what else am I not doing ?!?!

Comment: how are you building your type script into a js file?

Comment: first I download and install visual typeScript plug,
then my project is an empty template of web application and  I add the ts file. when I save that file it builds automatically the js file along side a js.map file.

Comment: `<script src="address.js"></script>` and `<script src="Customer.js"></script>`: your error is here. Maybe you should follow [a tutorial for SystemJS](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/)?

Comment: I will try it.
thanks

Answer (score 8):

I've just solved this.  Or rather I found a blog post that does https://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/.  To follow the proper SO guidelines I will reproduce it here.

Why you get 'exports is undefined' is due to Visual Studio transpiling to use `commonjs` modules.  I looked at this for days trying different things and the message seemed to be that commonjs is the default and should "just work" (TM).  But doesn't.  I don't know what is missing - perhaps VS needs some include.  I couldn't work out what.

The transpiled class using `commonjs` will include lines like this at the top and bottom of the .js file:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
...
exports.SpeciesClass = SpeciesClass;
```

This is your error.

The solution that worked for me was to use `requirejs`.  It is an implementation of AMD (http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).  It still uses `exports` but wraps it in a `define`:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    ...
    exports.SpeciesClass = SpeciesClass;
```

What follows is pretty-much the blog post https://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/.  With some modifications for the most recent version of Typescript.  Unfortunately where I'm working I don't have access to github (or anything like that) so I can only paste my files in here.

I also had to allow for some issues with Visual Studio.  I found that despite configuring the `project.csproj`'s `<TypescriptModuleKind>` to be `AMD`, it seemed to always default to `commonjs`.  So I transpile manually and hope to find a solution to stop VS defaulting.

I created a `tsconfig.json` file (`tsc --init`) and set the `module` to `amd`. I added a `"Files": ["*.ts"]`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "amd",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', commonjs

    /* ... */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
  },
  "Files" : ["*.ts"]
}
```

Commented out lines (with defaults) removed.

After starting the server, Visual Studio would transpile the files (using `commonjs` module format).  Requiring me to run `tsc` to force the files to transpile to use the `amd` module format.  And it worked (no errors seen in the developer console).

First the files layout (from blogpost).  What I have is the same except i've called my file `index.html` as `default.htm` reminds me of the bad ole days.  You can get `require.js` from http://requirejs.org/.  And `require.d.ts` from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/requirejs (save the `index.d.ts` as `require.d.ts`).

[image: files layout]

#### Greeter.ts

```
export class Greeter {
    element: HTMLElement;
    span: HTMLElement;
    timerToken: number;

    constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        this.element = element;
        this.element.innerText += "The time is: ";
        this.span = document.createElement('span');
        this.element.appendChild(this.span);
        this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString();
    }

    start() {
        this.timerToken = setInterval(() => this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString(), 500);
    }

    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
    }

}
```

#### AppConfig.ts

```
import { AppMain } from "./AppMain"

require(['AppMain'], 
    (main: any) => {
        var appMain = new AppMain();
        appMain.run();
    }
);
```

#### AppMain.ts

```
import { Greeter } from "./classes/Greeter"

export class AppMain {
    public run() {
        // code from window.onload
        var dummyEl: HTMLElement = document.createElement('span');
        var theEl: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('content');;
        var el: HTMLElement = theEl !== null ? theEl : dummyEl;
        var greeter: Greeter = new Greeter(el);
        greeter.start();
    }
};
```

Or use:

```
        var theEl: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('content');
        var greeter: Greeter = new Greeter(theEl);
```

And just realise that what is called an 'error' when you transpile is just a warning!:

```
app/AppMain.ts(7,13): error TS2322: Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
```

#### app.ts

No longer used

#### index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
        <!--
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app/classes/Greeter.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        -->
        <script data-main="app/AppConfig" type="text/javascript" src="lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know it has been some time but I just didn't saw.|
thank you for the deep explanation and help.
@HankCa

Comment: No worries @user24136!

Comment: Can provide a download link to this working source code?

Answer (score 1):

CommonJs isn't needed. Wrap all typescript in a common namespace and then export other namespaces, class, etc. Does offer intellisense:

**MyClass1.ts**

```
namespace GlobalNamespace {
     export class MyClass1 {
         prop1:string;
     }
}
```

**MyClass2.ts**

```
namespace GlobalNamespace {
     export class MyClass2 {
          prop2:string;
     }
}
```

Divide into namespace units:

**SubClasses.ts**

```
namespace GlobalNamespace {
     export namespace SubNamespace1 {
        export class SubClass1 {
             myClass1: MyClass1;
        }
     }
}

namespace GlobalNamespace {
     export namespace SubNamespace2 {
        export class SubClass2 {
             subClass1:SubNamespace1.SubClass1;
        }
     }
}
```

Instantiate SubClass2

```
var subClass2 = new GlobalNamespace.SubNamespace2.SubClass2();
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanx!!!
Just need to clarify - every `namespace XX{export namespaceYY{...} }` may be located in a separate TS file