# How to import a class in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, module, export, loading

I am new to typescript programming. I tried to create a very simple project running in the browser using typescript.

When I run the application I get following error;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

I understand the problem is loading the class. But I am not really sure how to get this fixed.

Can anyone provide some assistance please?

I saw several sites that I need to use a module loader to do this. But couldn't find any examples showing how to do this.

I have following files in the app

person.ts

```
    export class Person{
    greet()
    {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
import {Person} from './person'
let p = new Person();
p.greet();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                         
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "strict": true                          
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "lite-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: [this answer should sort it out for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649220/visual-studio-typescript-uncaught-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined-at/48436147#48436147)

Comment: It's not relevant to TypeScript but to JavaScript and how to handle ES6 module. You can use SystemJs for loading modules or make a bundle of all modules into a plain javascript file understandable by any browser, for example with parcel, rollup or webpack.

Comment: Other option for a "toy project" : use [typescript namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) instead of ES6 modules. TSC (typescript compiler) can compile and make a bundle of typescript files easily if they used namespace. It's less clean than ES6 module but it can help you start with TypeScript then you can learn how to handle ES6 modules.