# typescript - simple module example fails

Tags: typescript, import, module, export

Person.ts:

```
export class Person {
  private _name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
  }
  get name(): string {return this._name};
}
```

test.ts:

```
import {Person} from "./Person";

var user = new Person("John");
document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = user.name;
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
    ,"outDir" : "build"
  }
}
```

When opening the result in Chrome, the following error is shown on the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at test.js:2
```

Comment: see this comment
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33294807/4096589
the browser does not know about commonjs modules

Comment: which browser are you using? maybe you are missing a polyfill :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769278/1977315

1. install requireJs

   ```
   npm install requirejs
   ```
2. include requireJs in the html page

   ```
   <h1 id="h1"></h1>
   <script src="../node_modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="test.js"></script>
   ```
3. compile the code with the module amd arg:

   ```
   tsc -module amd
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your app compatible with browsers.
for example using webpack:

```
> npm install webpack -g
> webpack build/test.js bundle.js
```

and in your html

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Typescript compilation will compile your files with commonjs module resolution,
Which will not work in browsers (nodejs uses commonjs).
Webpack is an example for a bundler that will take you app and make it browser ready.

Answer (score 0):

The transpiled code is below:

```js
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Person = (function () {
        function Person(name) {
            this._name = name;
        }
        Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "name", {
            get: function () { return this._name; },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
        ;
        return Person;
    }());
    exports.Person = Person;
});
```

however if you see that this expects browsers to understand the module system and in this case requirejs. If you wish you can just take the snippet and use it - its perfectly fine ES5 code.

```js
var Person = (function() {
  function Person(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }
  Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "name", {
    get: function() {
      return this._name;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });;
  return Person;
}());
```

Comment: Unfortunately modules default to CommonJS